# Update to Angular 9 fails

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-upgrade, angular9

I use Angular 8 in my project and would like to upgrade to Angular 9.

I follow [upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l3) and when I run command: 
`ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`,

I get an error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
```

Update: 403 error is gone but now I get following errors:

```
Package "@angular/core" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "9.0.1").
Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/animations" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/forms" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/common" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/platform-server" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/compiler" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "9.0.1").
Package "@angular/service-worker" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/router" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/platform-browser" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "7.0.4" (extended), would install "9.0.1").
```

**SOLVED:**
I've added tslib to package.json

Comment: Are you doing it inside of a company network?

Comment: No, my private network at home

Comment: I can access link https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli in browser and see a huge json file

Comment: Npm currently has some problems. Try again in few hours.

Comment: 403 error is gone but new errors are shown, please see my updated question

Comment: @aponski Please mark my answer as valid, I received already 3 Upvote,

Answer (score 4):

Experienced the same issue.

Was able to successfully update from Angular 7 to 8 using:

```
ng update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8
```

However, trying to update from Angular 8 to 9 using:

```
ng update @angular/cli@9 @angular/core@9
```

Gave me this error:

```
Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/animations" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/common" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/compiler" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/core" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/forms" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/platform-browser" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/platform-server" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/router" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
Package "@angular/service-worker" has a missing peer dependency of "tslib" @ "^1.10.0".
```

Which I solved by adding the suggested version of `tslib` to `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue after the update to angular9.
First I updated angular8 completely then update to angular9.

```sh
ng update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8
```

Second, I update the below command.

```sh
ng update @angular/cli@9 @angular/core@9
```

Please follow the link: 
[How to Update till Angular9](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0)